# How to launch openssh on windows10 64bit?

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-10, openssh

I failed to launch openssh on windows10 64bit. After finish the installation, I followed below instructions to setup passwd:

```
1.  Open a command prompt and change to the installation directory (Program Files\OpenSSH is the default).

2.  CD into the bin directory.

3.  Use mkgroup to create a group permissions file. For local groups, use the "-l" switch. For domain groups, use the "-d" switch.
    For both domain and local, it is best to run the command twice (remember to use >>, not >). If you use both, make sure to edit the file to remove any duplicate entires.

      mkgroup -l >> ..\etc\group      (local groups)

4.  Use mkpasswd to add authorized users into the passwd file. For local users, use the "-l" switch. For domain users, use the "-d" switch.
    For both domain and local, it is best to run the command twice (remember to use >>, not >). If you use both, make sure to edit the file to remove any duplicate entires.

      mkpasswd -l >> ..\etc\passwd      (local users)
```

I have disabled the windows10 default ssh service. So the port 22 is available. After that I tried to launch the sshd server but failed.
Below is the error I got.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH>net start opensshd
The OpenSSH Server service is starting.
The OpenSSH Server service could not be started.

A system error has occurred.

System error 1067 has occurred.

The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

How can I configure the sshd on windows10 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

It turn out that I installed a very old version of `openssh`. It works fine after I upgrade to `openssh 7.5`.